# Accessing published Meteor data

Tags: javascript, meteor

Not sure if I'm going about this the right way. I'll map out what I'm trying to achieve and please give me any feedback you can. Also very new to meteor so sorry if I'm a bit uneducated in some aspects. This is going to be a two player game where users login in with accounts-twitter or accounts-facebook. Here's the tricky part it will only initialize the game if there are two users logged in. To figure out who is logged in I have put this line of code in my server portion:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
 Meteor.publish("userStatus", function() {
       return Meteor.users.find({
       "status.online": true
       })
    });
 }
```

My idea of what needs to be done is write an if statement if(userStatus === true){get a users "_id"} then push that user into an array and have a for loop run through every 2 users signed on in the array and initialize a game for them. Also the **main question is how do I grab the users ID if status.online is true?** Also any input on how to make this more efficient is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your "main question," you would do this with a mongoDB for-each like so.

```
Meteor.methods({

getOnline : function(){
    var retArr = new Array();
    Meteor.users.find({"status.online": true}).forEach(function(u){
        retArr.push(u._id); //populated retArr with the id of users online
    });
    return retArr;        
}
});
```

If I left out something or you need clarification on something, please comment.

Comment: Alright should I completely delete my Meteor.publish part of the code or does that stay? @mjkaufer

Comment: If you're going to be using `Meteor.methods`, you shouldn't need a `Meteor.publish`